# Unnecessary numbering is came for equation parts

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

I am on writing the following equation, but I am facing a problem that equation numbering is coming for the different steps of the same equation.

[image]

The MWE as follows,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}
    \begin{align}
        & L_{B_{1} A_{1}} L_{B_{0} A_{0}}\left(\left|I_{1}\right\rangle\right) =L_{B_{1} A_{1}} L_{B_{0} A_{0}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{m}} \sum_{b=0}^{2^{m}-1} \sum_{a=0}^{2^{m}-1}\left|P_{b a}\right\rangle\left|b^{\prime}\right\rangle\left|a^{\prime}\right\rangle\right)\\
        & =\frac{1}{2^{m}}\Biggl(\underset{b a \neq B_{0} A_{0}, B_{1} A_{1}}{\displaystyle\sum_{b=0}^{2^{m}-1} \sum_{a=0}^{2^{m}-1}}\left|P_{ba}\right\rangle\left|b^{\prime}\right\rangle\left|a^{\prime}\right\rangle \begin{aligned}[t] & +U_{B A}\left(\left|P_{B_{0} A_{0}}\right|\right)\left|B_{0} A_{0}\right\rangle\\
            & +U_{B A}\left(\left|P_{B_{1} A_{1}}\right\rangle\right)\left|B_{1} A_{1}\right\rangle\Biggr)
        \end{aligned}\\
        & =\frac{1}{2^{m}}
        \Biggl( \underset{b a \neq B_{0} A_{0}, B_{1} A_{1}}{\sum_{b=0}^{2^{m}-1} \sum_{a=0}^{2^{m}-1}}\hspace*{-0.5em}\left|P_{b a}\right\rangle\left|b^{\prime}\right\rangle\left|a^{\prime}\right\rangle
        \begin{aligned}[t] &+\left|p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{2} p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{3^{\prime}} \cdots p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{0^{\prime}} p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{1^{\prime}}\right\rangle\left|B_{0} A_{0}\right\rangle \\
            &+\left|p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{2^{\prime}} p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{3^{\prime}} \cdots p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{0^{\prime}} p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{1^{\prime}}\right\rangle\left|B_{1} A_{1}\right\rangle\Biggr)
        \end{aligned}
        \label{lb1a1}
    \end{align}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

Somebody please help me to remove the unnecessary numbering (1) and (2) for the steps.

Comment: `\notag` on the lines you don't want numbered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wish to obtain a single equation number, I suggest you replace the `align` environment with a nested pair of `equation` and `aligned` environments. I would also look to adopt `\ket`-type notation quickly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket\lvert\rangle

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{lb1a1}
\begin{aligned}[b]
& L_{B_1 A_1} L_{B_0 A_0} (\ket{1}) 
  =L_{B_1 A_1} L_{B_0 A_0} 
  \biggl( \frac{1}{2^m} 
     \sum_{b=0}^{2^m\mkern-2mu-1} 
     \sum_{a=0}^{2^m\mkern-2mu-1} 
     \ket{P_{b a}} \ket{b'} \ket{a'} \biggr)\\
&=
  \begin{multlined}[t]
  \frac{1}{2^m} \biggl(\,
  \smash[b]{\underset{\mathclap{ba\neq B_0A_0, B_1A_1}}{
     \sum_{b=0}^{2^m\mkern-2mu-1} 
     \sum_{a=0}^{2^m\mkern-2mu-1}}}
     \ket{P_{ba}} \ket{b'} \ket{a'} 
        +U_{B A}(\abs{P_{B_0 A_0}})\ket{B_0 A_0}\\
        +U_{B A}(\ket{P_{B_1 A_1}})\ket{B_1 A_1} \smash{\biggr)}
  \end{multlined}\\
&=
  \begin{multlined}[t]
  \frac{1}{2^m} \biggl( \,
  \smash[b]{\underset{\mathclap{ba\neq B_0A_0, B_1A_1}}{
      \sum_{b=0}^{2^m\mkern-2mu-1} 
      \sum_{a=0}^{2^m\mkern-2mu-1}}}
      \ket{P_{b a}} \ket{b'} \ket{a'}
      +\ket[\big]{p_{B_0 A_0}^{2} p_{B_0 A_0}^{3'} \dots p_{B_0 A_0}^{0'} p_{B_0 A_0}^{1'}}  
       \ket[\big]{B_0 A_0} \\
      +\ket[\big]{p_{B_1 A_1}^{2'} p_{B_1 A_1}^{3'} \dots p_{B_1 A_1}^{0'} p_{B_1 A_1}^{1'}} 
       \ket[\big]{B_1 A_1} \smash[t]{\biggr)}
    \end{multlined}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tough alignment.

I'd make the first line to have zero width, so we can exploit the symmetry in the following line and align at the `=` signs and at the `+` signs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\KET}{\lvert}{\rangle}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ket}{som}{%
  \mathinner{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      {\KET*{#3}}
      {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\KET{#3}}{\KET[#2]{#3}}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
& \lefteqn{
    L_{B_{1} A_{1}} L_{B_{0} A_{0}}(\ket{I_{1}})
    =L_{B_{1} A_{1}} L_{B_{0} A_{0}}\biggl(
      \frac{1}{2^{m}}
      \sum_{b=0}^{2^{m}-1}
      \sum_{a=0}^{2^{m}-1}\ket{P_{b a}}\ket{b'}\ket{a'}
    \biggr)
   }
\notag
\\
&= \frac{1}{2^{m}}\biggl(
     \smash[b]{
       \underset{b a \neq B_{0} A_{0}, B_{1} A_{1}}{
         \displaystyle\sum_{b=0}^{2^{m}-1} \sum_{a=0}^{2^{m}-1}
       }
     }
     \hspace{-0.5em}
     \ket{P_{ba}}\ket{b'}\ket{a'}
     &&+ U_{B A}(\ket{P_{B_{0} A_{0}}})\ket{B_{0} A_{0}}
\notag
\\
&    &&+ U_{B A}(\ket{P_{B_{1} A_{1}}})\ket{B_{1} A_{1}}
   \biggr)
\notag
\\
&= \frac{1}{2^{m}}
   \biggl(
     \smash[b]{
       \underset{b a \neq B_{0} A_{0}, B_{1} A_{1}}{
         \displaystyle\sum_{b=0}^{2^{m}-1} \sum_{a=0}^{2^{m}-1}
       }
     }
     \hspace{-0.5em}
     \ket{P_{b a}}\ket{b'}\ket{a'}
     &&+ \ket[\big]{
           p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{2} p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{3'}
           \cdots
           p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{0'} p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{1'}
         }
         \ket{B_{0} A_{0}}
\notag
\\
&    && +\ket[\big]{
           p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{2'} p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{3'}
           \cdots p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{0'}
           p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{1'}
         }
         \ket{B_{1} A_{1}}
   \biggr)
\label{lb1a1}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

I defined a `\ket` command to avoid clumsy combinations of `\left` and `\right`. Using `\mathinner` ensures a bit of horizontal spacing between two kets.

[image]

Comment: +1 for also replacing all instances of `^{\prime}` with `'`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I insert `\nonumber` at the end of lines which I want LaTeX to skip over when numbering. So you can choose only the third line to get numbered by placing `\nonumber` on the first and second lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{fleqn}
        \begin{align}
            & L_{B_{1} A_{1}} L_{B_{0} A_{0}}\left(\left|I_{1}\right\rangle\right) =L_{B_{1} A_{1}} L_{B_{0} A_{0}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{m}} \sum_{b=0}^{2^{m}-1} \sum_{a=0}^{2^{m}-1}\left|P_{b a}\right\rangle\left|b^{\prime}\right\rangle\left|a^{\prime}\right\rangle\right) \nonumber\\
            & =\frac{1}{2^{m}}\Biggl(\underset{b a \neq B_{0} A_{0}, B_{1} A_{1}}{\displaystyle\sum_{b=0}^{2^{m}-1} \sum_{a=0}^{2^{m}-1}}\left|P_{ba}\right\rangle\left|b^{\prime}\right\rangle\left|a^{\prime}\right\rangle \begin{aligned}[t] & +U_{B A}\left(\left|P_{B_{0} A_{0}}\right|\right)\left|B_{0} A_{0}\right\rangle\\
                & +U_{B A}\left(\left|P_{B_{1} A_{1}}\right\rangle\right)\left|B_{1} A_{1}\right\rangle\Biggr)
            \end{aligned} \nonumber \\
            & =\frac{1}{2^{m}}
            \Biggl( \underset{b a \neq B_{0} A_{0}, B_{1} A_{1}}{\sum_{b=0}^{2^{m}-1} \sum_{a=0}^{2^{m}-1}}\hspace*{-0.5em}\left|P_{b a}\right\rangle\left|b^{\prime}\right\rangle\left|a^{\prime}\right\rangle
            \begin{aligned}[t] &+\left|p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{2} p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{3^{\prime}} \cdots p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{0^{\prime}} p_{B_{0} A_{0}}^{1^{\prime}}\right\rangle\left|B_{0} A_{0}\right\rangle \\
                &+\left|p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{2^{\prime}} p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{3^{\prime}} \cdots p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{0^{\prime}} p_{B_{1} A_{1}}^{1^{\prime}}\right\rangle\left|B_{1} A_{1}\right\rangle\Biggr)
            \end{aligned}
            \label{lb1a1}
        \end{align}
    \end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

[image: Equation block from post but without numbering on first or second lines, and (1) on third line]